# "map passwd uid" equivalent in sssd

Tags: ldap, sssd

nslcd.conf has "map passwd  uid" to map attributes that will be used as the Login username. What is the sssd.conf equivalent of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
ldap_user_name
```

Comment: Right.  `man sssd-ldap` gives a list of all the possible mappings; each field can be uniquely mapped if necessary.